# Linked Server related

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two instances of SQL Server:

- Server1 (SQL Server 2008)
- Server2 (SQL Server 2005)

I am executing a stored procedure from Server1 which references tables on Server2.

It is working fine in my test environment:

- Server1 runs Vista SP2, SQL Server 2008;
- Server2 runs Windows XP SP2, SQL Server 2005.

However, it is not working in the production environment:

- Server1 runs Vista SP1, SQL Server 2008;
- Server2 runs Windows XP SP2, SQL Server 2005.

The error message I receive is:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Server2" returned message "No transaction is active.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Server2" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Comment: Greate I like  Aaronaught editing, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Article on above issue is published on SQLVillage.com http://www.sqlvillage.com/Articles/Distributed%20Transaction%20Issue%20for%20Linked%20Server%20in%20SQL%20Server%202008.asp

Comment: Answer doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to disable remote transactions all together if you do not need to update the remote tables.

Go to the properties of the linked server (assuming you are using one)
Select "Server Options" and set "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions" to "False".

It worked for me. ;)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! In my case I was trying to call a scalar function on the remote server which just gathers data and performs some calculations, no table updates needed.

Answer (score 1):

The "unable to begin a distributed transaction" usually means that DTC is disabled on one or both of the machines.  To resolve:

- Start->Run `dcomcnfg`
- Expand Component Services, Computers
- Right-click My Computer, go to Properties
- Click MSDTC tab
- On Vista: Click "Default Properties" tab, check "Enable Distributed COM on this computer"
- On XP: Click "MSDTC" tab, click "Security Configuration", check "Network DTC Access".
- Click OK, restart MSDTC.

If that doesn't solve the issue then you may be experiencing this: [KB954950](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954950).  Have you made sure to install all the updates?

Failing that I'd probably head over to serverfault, I think they're more knowledgeable about this stuff...

Comment: I Have checked "Enable Distributed COM on this computer" This option already on

Comment: @rmdussa: Make sure you've checked it on *all* computers, then see my update.  Hope you get this solved.

Comment: Yes both computers have enabled DTC

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured [MSDTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146(VS.85).aspx) in production?

Two common causes are DTC not being started on one or all machines, and not having a suitable domain account for all DTC's